# Why is it recommended to use `go build` instead of `go run` when running a Go app in production?

Tags: go

I have a Dockerfile that I used to compile the Go app using `go build`. I researched and indeed `go build` is recommended for production.

However I cannot find a proper answer as to why.

I understand `go run` creates a temporary file that and that cleans up on app termination.
But if I am using Docker, why is it bad to use `go run` instead of `go build`?

Comment: `go run` is handy for: 1. Single file helpers 2. To run a command. You basically cannot use `go run` with multiple file arguments correctly, only go run with a directory or import path argument is safe to use.

Comment: «For me this is a valid question that I have not found any answer to anywhere...» I'd conjure most downvoters assume the question violates so-called "common sense": if you run `go help run`, you'll see «Run compiles and runs the named main Go package.»; since Go is a compiled language, doing compilation each time a program is about to be run appears to be nonsensical—unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise: after all, you'd not re-compile `cat` or `ls` each time before running them, right?

Comment: …so the next logical step in the thought process of a typocal downvoter—as I think it is—is that you just have learned about `go run` in some random blog post and got done with it without actually questioning the approach. I mean, (bad) Go HOWTOs love citing `go run` as it appears to provide quicker "time to market" for the "hello world" program: you run a single command (`go run`) instead of two (`go build` or `go install`, then the compiled binary itself).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Several reasons:

- A Go application does not require the Go toolchain, just as a C application doesn't require `gcc`. If you use `go build`, you can just deploy a binary; if you use `go run`, you have to install the toolchain.
- `go run` compiles the application unnecessarily every time it's run, increasing startup times.
- `go run` forks the application to a new process, making process management unnecessarily complicated by obscuring PIDs and exit statuses.
- `go run` has the potential to unexpectedly absorb code changes when you're only intending to run an application. Using `go build` only when you want a fresh binary allows you to re-run the same, consistent binary every time with no unexpected changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Adrian. Is the process management bit relevant if I am using Docker? I will edit the body of my question, but my main concern here is whether it is okay to use Go run in Docker. Your last item seems concerning, but I'm not sure how much of that applies if I am using docker.

Comment: Yes, process management is still relevant; processes are still processes, even if they're running in a container. I'd ask instead: do you have a good reason to use `go run` instead of following best practices? If not, just do it the right way.

Comment: One more reason: `go run` obscures exit statuses (stati? [actually it might be "statuus", but it's really just "statuses"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/877/what-is-the-plural-form-of-status)) as noted in several filed issues. This isn't going to be fixed, because there's no correct fix anyway, but here's one of them: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13440