# Linux System.d Unit Service Doesn't See My Specific Environment Variable

Tags: linux, go

I have a basic "service unit" file like the following.

```
[Unit]
Description=Certprovider service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/home/mert/certprovider/certprovider
WorkingDirectory=/home/mert
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have the **.env** file in the root of the project.

```
CA_DIR_URL=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
EMAIL=mertsmsk0@gmail.com

HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=8557
```

I load this file with the following lines.

```
err := godotenv.Load()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error loading .env file")
}
```

Service has been working very well but I cannot reach the **PORT** environment variable. Thus I cannot start the webserver because that port cannot listen. I print all the environment variables that in the **.env** excluding **PORT**. I changed its name to **APP_PORT** but it same thing.

The mystery part is I can reach other variables in the **.env** file. In addition to that when I add the following line in the unit file, I can reach that variable but I don't understand that why should I add only the **PORT** variable in the unit file?

```
[Service]
Environment=PORT=8557
```

It's happening when I try to run it as a binary file. Because I can reach the variables with the following command.

```
go run .
```

Comment: There's Go code in the question, and it's relevant to the answer, so I'd argue it's a valid SO question.  I also appreciate you including the relevant details without having to be asked, @Mert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If you call Load without any args it will default to loading env in the current path](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/joho/godotenv#hdr-If_you_call_Load_without_any_args_it_will_default_to_loading__env_in_the_current_path).

Your current path is configured here:

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/mert
```

And yet, you say (emphasis added)

> I have the .env file in the *root of the project.*

But that's *not* the current working directory.

> root of the project

That concept is not meaningful to the application runtime.  Unlike interpreted languages like, say, PHP, Go compiles to a static binary that is functionally *entirely* distinct from the set of libraries and sources that define it.  In PHP (or python, ruby, etc) those libraries have no other place to *be*, than the root of some project directory.

In go, that stuff is only relevant for development and testing.  The fact that your executable appears to be in your "root of the project" is entirely incidental and completely meaningless.

If you *really* want to put the runtime configuration in tht particular file, in that particular place, just set *that* as the working directory:

```
ExecStart=/home/mert/certprovider/certprovider
WorkingDirectory=/home/mert/certprovider/certprovider
```

I would put that stuff in `/usr/local` so I didn't accidentally break my let's encrypt while fiddling with stuff in my home directory - doubly so for let's encrypt because it might take up to 90 days to realize your certs weren't being refreshed.  I'd put the config outside of my home directory for the same reason.

Actually, for this case I'd probably put all the config in the unit file.  Why *not* put it there?  But of course, that's a matter of opinion.  If you really want to use the automatic `.env` discovery then you should dedicate a directory to containing that hidden file.  It doesn't make much sense to put a config specific to *one* application in `~/.env`.

Wherever you put `.env`, make sure that's your working directory so it will be discovered.

> I print all the environment variables that in the .env excluding PORT. I changed its name to APP_PORT but it same thing. [...]
> The mystery part is I can reach other variables in the .env file.

Respectfully, that sounds like an assumption on your part.  Without evidence to the contrary, it's easy to conclude that you have set defaults for these values or that they're coming from some other source or behavior.  That's more parsimonious than concluding the `godotenv` library read some, but not all, the values from a file.

> It's happening when I try to run it as a binary file. Because I can reach the variables with the following command. [`go run .`]

Go *always* runs as a binary.  `go run .` simply automatically builds the binary in a temp location and then runs it.  [Why is it recommended to use `go build` instead of `go run` when running a Go app in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060768/why-is-it-recommended-to-use-go-build-instead-of-go-run-when-running-a-go-ap) talks about why `go run` is often contraindicated on SO.

Comment: I really like the community. I appreciate your quick and obvious answer. I just tested and it's as you said. It worked well. Thanks a lot! By the way, I can read other environment variables because I forgot the invisible environment variable file in the old working directory ridiculously.

Comment: I don't know.  With the information you provided, I  don't think we *can* know.  If  could demonstrate the behavior you describe, it would be a much more enticing mystery

Comment: I edited my first comment,  I forgot the invisible environment variable file in the old working directory ridiculously. Thus it loads another **.env** file.

Comment: The most important point here is the one about the project directory.  Source code doesn't matter at runtime - not its location, not anything else about it is relevant when running a program.  Even with `go run .` the only connection is incidental : the current working directory.  Happy coding, mate